# How to add multiple values in ToolTip in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tooltip

I want to add data from 2 columns from a datagrid and display them using a single tooltip. I am able to achieve the result from 1 column only but when I try to concatenate the values doesn't show up.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="4 0" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  >
   <ToolTip>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                   <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="SourceName"/>
                   <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Message"/>
         </MultiBinding>
   </ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

`SourceName` and `Message` are the values extracted from properties.
How do I show both of them in a single Tooltip ?

Comment: Are you getting any binding exception?

Comment: Is it shown if you use only one binding?

Answer (score 2):

`ToolTip` should be a part of the `TextBlock` element

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="4 0" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  >
   <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock>
             <TextBlock.Text>
                  <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                      <Binding Path="SourceName"/>
                      <Binding Path="Message" />
                  </MultiBinding>
             </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
   </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Probably, the bindings should be also changed if you want to get information from the DataContext and not from the visual element.

Comment: Will `<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="SourceName"/>` work? As the in this case framework will look for SourceName and Message property in TextBlock instead of DataContext of control.

Comment: @user1672994 thanks for the hint. Of course, the binding should be changed if information comes from DataContext